# I can't change background image, tailwind nextjs

Tags: css, next.js, background, tailwind-css, background-image

i' ve tried all the possible ways to change my app background with an image but can't succeded, i'm using next 14 with tailwind. Here is one example of how i've tryed to change the background:
//page.tsx

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="h-full bg-tech bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-center bg-fixed">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

//tailwind.config.ts

```
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'tech': "url('/public/assets/sfondo (1).avif')",
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
export default config
```

I've also tryed giving to the div my own class and use it in the global.css file as normal css using the key "background-image" but can't figure it out.

Comment: Try to replace `'tech': "url('/public/assets/sfondo (1).avif')",` with `'tech': "url('../public/assets/sfondo (1).avif')",`

Comment: Yes it worked, i fixed the tailwind.config file in this way : 'tech': "url('../../public/assets/sfondo (1).avif')" and the the div in this way: <div className="h-screen bg-cover bg-tech">

Comment: Great so answer your own question

Comment: I could not, i got an answer warning, waiting it will disapper and i will answer. Greetings

Comment: I post my piece of code here how i solved the issue `'tech': "url('../../public/assets/sfondo4.avif')",`